# How to stop Rotation in JS Typewriter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a script on Codepen that mimics a type effect. https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/jkivt

In my page, I have an input that locates user location using GeoIP. This Codepen prevents the GeoIP from loading due to rotation fundtion that prevents the location from being inserted. The GeoIP is loaded using 'window.onload'.

Any suggestions?

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa
}

h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'></span>
</h1>
<h2>A single &lt;span&gt; is all you need.</h2>
```

By the way, this is the following conflicting script as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  $.getJSON( "http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function(data){  
 $.ajax({

    url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip="+data.ip,
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data)
    {

if(data)
{
document.getElementById("presidence").value = data['geoplugin_city']+','+data['geoplugin_region']+','+data['geoplugin_countryName']+'.';
}
else
{
alert('hy');

}
    
    }
   })
 } );
};
```

```html
<input id="presidence" type="text" readonly  size="30" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign one function to `window.onload`, if somewhere else in the script, some other function is assigned to `window.onload` (before the event has triggered), the reference to the first function will be lost, and only the last function assigned to `onload` will run. This is why assigning to `onload` generally isn't a great idea - it's limited to holding a reference to only one function. Use `addEventListener` instead, which can handle a (mostly) unlimited number of attached functions. For readability, define the typewriter load function, and define your user location load function, then use `addEventListener` for both:

```
function typewriterLoad() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
}

function userlocationLoad() {
  $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function(data) {
    $.ajax({

      url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" + data.ip,
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {

        if (data) {
          document.getElementById("presidence").value = data['geoplugin_city'] + ',' + data['geoplugin_region'] + ',' + data['geoplugin_countryName'] + '.';
        } else {
          alert('hy');
        }
      }
    })
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', typewriterLoad);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', userlocationLoad);
```

An alternative is to make only a *single* listener, and pass it a function that calls both:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  typewriterLoad();
  userlocationLoad();
});
```

Comment: This has worked in my application. Much appreciated. I have learnt something new with the help.